# How to simulate an Android firmware update on Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I'm running the latest Android Studio (2.3.3) on my machine, and I would like to know how to update from an Android version to another without losing apps.

I'm trying to emulate a Google Pixel XL with firmware 7.1, installed my test app, and then when I tried to change from Advance Settings my firmware version to the latest, Android O (8), I noticed that all the third party apps were deleted, and it sees my device as a new one with factory reset.

Do you have any solution for this problem? My purpose is to see if the upgrade affected my app in any way.